# Prometheus Metrics to StackDriver Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, stackdriver

We need to monitor the Neo4j hosted in GCP VM's instance for which we are using Prometheus. Neo4j Natively supports sending metrics to Prometheus.

Now we need to create a dashboard using the stack driver monitoring with the exposed prometheus metrics.

Any suggestions/help will be useful.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried to find something elaborated about this particular scenario but all I found was related with GKE and prometheus as a sidecar. However, the configuration must be similar and probably you will find [this documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/prometheus-and-stackdriver-fb8f7524ece0) useful. This guide will also lead you to [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus) official documentation.

Also found another user of neo4j trying to do something similar and there is an [answer](https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-metrics-to-stackdriver/8935) that maybe you should check. For logging neo4j to Stackdriver Logging, see [this](https://medium.com/neo4j/configuring-stackdriver-logging-for-neo4j-vms-on-gcp-d175f32e2e1b).